# How to paginate category

Tags: python, django

How do i paginate men_clothing_shirt, it is under Category. See image of my template.

[image]

```
def men_shirt(request):
queryset_list = Category.objects.filter(name='man_clothing_shirt')  
paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 1)
page = request.GET.get('page')
try:
    queryset = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    queryset = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
context = {
'menshirtpaginator': queryset,
}
return render(request,'men_shirt.html', context)
```

Comment: What is wrong with you code? Do you get any errors? Or you are looking for the front end part? And also do you want to list only 1 item per page?

Comment: I want all item on page to be listed according as implemented on the views.py. The problem is all item is listed on page when Paginator (queryset_list, 1).

Comment: In your front-end, do you have `?page=1` in the url you are sending request to?

Comment: i just updated my question, you can view the image of my template. If there is something i could change, just let me know. @aminrd

Comment: when Paginator is changed to 1,  i can still see all my item display on the page, instead of just a single item. But next and previous works. The problem here is to make just one item display on page when i change the pagination to 1. @aminrd

Comment: Please can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: Can you post what is rendered in your front-end?

Comment: i have updated my question, i added the image of my front end, you can take a look at it. @aminrd

Answer (score 0):

I suggest minor updates in your `views.py`. I cannot see what is being rendered in your front-end yet. I added some comments in the code for updates. When you post the front-end part, we can more debug deeply.

```py
def men_shirt(request):
    queryset_list = Category.objects.all().filter(name='man_clothing_shirt')  
    paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 1)

    # First of all, if no page exists is in the url, always choose the first page
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)

    # .get_page method is safer method than .page based on Django documentation and you do not have to be worry about its existence

    queryset = paginator.get_page(page)

    context = {
    'menshirtpaginator': queryset,
    }

    return render(request,'men_shirt.html', context)
```

Comment: i think the problem is that pagination do not work nn filter(name='man_clothing_shirt')  , i think it only works on objects.all(). I have tried all i could but still not working. When pagination is changed to paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 1), it shows all my items on the page instead of just one. That is the problem. @aminrd

Comment: @Hi3e Have you tried `Category.objects.all().filter(name='man_clothing_shirt') `?

Comment: @Hi3e Can you post the rest of your template? How do you render objects in 'menshirtpaginator`? You are using a for loop?

Comment: I have attached image of my template to my question on how i render paginator. You can see it for yourself.